# Getting an error when trying to generate a page in Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework

Running command ionic generate page pages/test-page3 but getting below error message. Generating a component works though.

> ng generate page pages/test-page3 --project=app
> this.tree.readText is not a function
> [ERROR] Could not generate page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Updated Angular from 12 to 14 and the issue has gone. generate page works again.